# configure the alias field in the mapping.json in galaxybase-load

Tags: graph-databases

How to configure the "alias" field in the mapping.json file when the "hasHeader" field is set to false in galaxybase-load import tool?

I am using the import tool called galaxybase-load to import data. The import process requires a mapping.json file. I want to know how to configure the "alias" field in the mapping.json file when the value of the "hasHeader" field is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields "hasHeader" and "alias" have different meanings.

The "hasHeader" field indicates whether the data has a header. If the value of this field is set to "true," the first row will be treated as a header and not imported.

The "alias" field represents the attribute name of the corresponding column in the graph model. It should be configured along with the "columnIndex" field, which denotes the position of the column (counting from 0).

Together, "alias" and "columnIndex" establish the mapping relationship between the data source and the attributes of the graph model.